# qgis-bin.exe has stopped working

Tags: qgis, python

Working with a big (400mb) project with 25 esri shapefiles and a lot of layouting makes QGIS crash with 30min - 1hr intervals. Crashes usually happens when rendering data, and now ALWAYS when trying to export my print composer atlas ie I am totally unable to create ready map files. When trying to create an atlas, QGIS print composer starts rendering the export and often gets to 22% after which a "qgis-bin.exe has stopped working" popup is shown. I find no better / more detailed way of logging what is going than using DebugView, the attached logfile rows 23- is from when QGIS loads, and rows 130 (131?) - 136 are from when the crash happens. I am using QGIS 2.18.1 but all older versions tested gives the same kind of problem.

As I found no general information about how to debug and find reasons for these "qgis-bin.exe has stopped working" crashes, my questions in order to possible help to collect such good knowledge is:

- How do we in the best possible way log what could be causing errors in QGIS?
- What is known about these errors and how to fix them?
- Is there any way to check esri shapefiles for problems that might make qgis crash?
- Is there any way to check qgis files for problems that might make qgis crash (just manually going throught the xml files has given no results) ?

Debug log below

```
    00000001    0.00000000  [5344] d:\rs1\shell\windows.ui.shell\actioncenter\product\common\imageutilities.cpp(276)\Windows.UI.ActionCenter.dll!00007FF8A5FBC5B4: (caller: 00007FF8A5FACE34) LogHr(12) tid(16a8) 8000FFFF Oåterkalleligt fel   
00000002    1.34852946  [5344] Suspending   
00000003    6.27621698  [4488] ds\security\smartscreen\common\core\src\script_host.cpp(51)\smartscreen.exe!00007FF748135697: (caller: 00007FF748135DD8) Exception(1) tid(29a4) 80070001 Felaktig funktion.  
00000004    6.27621698  [4488]     Msg:[Unable to get property 'substr' of undefined or null reference - TypeError: Unable to get property 'substr' of undefined or null reference  
00000005    6.27621698  [4488]    at ShellCallbacks.isFileSupported (Unknown script code:1:2387)    
00000006    6.27621698  [4488]    at ShellCallbacks.prototype.getSamplingRate (Unknown script code:1:2988)  
00000007    6.27621698  [4488]    at Anonymous function (Unknown script code:1:925) 
00000008    6.27621698  [4488]    at Array.prototype.reduce (native code)   
00000009    6.27621698  [4488]    at CallbacksBase.prototype.getSamplingRates (Unknown script code:1:900)   
00000010    6.27621698  [4488]    at CallbacksBase.prototype.filterEvents (Unknown script code:1:2036)  
00000011    6.27621698  [4488]    at filterEvents (Unknown script code:1:43)    
00000012    6.27621698  [4488]    at _dispatch (Unknown script code:13:21)]     
00000013    6.27731228  [4488] ds\security\smartscreen\common\core\src\script_host.cpp(51)\smartscreen.exe!00007FF748135697: (caller: 00007FF748135DD8) Exception(2) tid(29a4) 80070001 Felaktig funktion.  
00000014    6.27731228  [4488]     Msg:[Unable to get property 'substr' of undefined or null reference - TypeError: Unable to get property 'substr' of undefined or null reference  
00000015    6.27731228  [4488]    at ShellCallbacks.isFileSupported (Unknown script code:1:2387)    
00000016    6.27731228  [4488]    at ShellCallbacks.prototype.getSamplingRate (Unknown script code:1:2988)  
00000017    6.27731228  [4488]    at Anonymous function (Unknown script code:1:925) 
00000018    6.27731228  [4488]    at Array.prototype.reduce (native code)   
00000019    6.27731228  [4488]    at CallbacksBase.prototype.getSamplingRates (Unknown script code:1:900)   
00000020    6.27731228  [4488]    at CallbacksBase.prototype.filterEvents (Unknown script code:1:2036)  
00000021    6.27731228  [4488]    at filterEvents (Unknown script code:1:43)    
00000022    6.27731228  [4488]    at _dispatch (Unknown script code:13:21)]     
00000023    6.37441492  [4992] Warning: loading of qgis translation failed [C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./i18n//qgis_en_US]    
00000024    6.37475920  [4992] Warning: loading of qt translation failed [C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qt4/translations/qt_en_US]    
00000025    7.95873356  [4992] Warning: QCss::Parser - Failed to load file  "/style.qss"    
00000026    8.34144592  [4992] Warning: QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to QgsPanelWidgetStack "mWidgetStack", which already has a layout 
00000027    14.20550251 [4992] Warning: libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile  
00000028    14.26776123 [1088] avcore\npsm\localprovider\baseprovider\lib\baseprovider.cpp(604)\NPSMDesktopProvider.dll!00007FF884262140: (caller: 00007FF8842626E5) ReturnHr(64) tid(141c) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.     
00000029    14.26824570 [1088] onecore\base\appmodel\resourcepolicy\gameconfigstore\client\gameconfigstoreclient.cpp(104)\resourcepolicyclient.dll!00007FF8C259976C: (caller: 00007FF8A71386C3) LogHr(37) tid(d9c) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.  
00000030    16.20186806 [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(728) tid(129c) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.   
00000031    16.20197678 [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(729) tid(c5c) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.    
00000032    16.20238113 [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(730) tid(f74) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.    
00000033    16.20257568 [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(731) tid(31ec) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.   
00000034    16.60998344 [1088] shell\explorer\taskband2\taskband2.cpp(4148)\Explorer.EXE!00007FF63FA3792A: (caller: 00007FF8C51C7DE3) ReturnHr(208) tid(b3c) 80004005 Odefinierat fel   
00000035    19.54531670 [1088] avcore\npsm\localprovider\baseprovider\lib\baseprovider.cpp(604)\NPSMDesktopProvider.dll!00007FF884262140: (caller: 00007FF8842626E5) ReturnHr(65) tid(141c) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.     
00000036    19.71704674 [1088] shell\explorer\taskband2\taskband2.cpp(4148)\Explorer.EXE!00007FF63FA3792A: (caller: 00007FF8C51C7DE3) ReturnHr(209) tid(b3c) 80004005 Odefinierat fel   
00000037    20.01391029 [1088] shell\explorer\taskband2\taskband2.cpp(4148)\Explorer.EXE!00007FF63FA3792A: (caller: 00007FF8C51C7DE3) ReturnHr(210) tid(b3c) 80004005 Odefinierat fel   
00000038    20.28680229 [4992] Warning: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 0h: PCS illuminant is not D50  
00000039    50.18239975 [1088] avcore\npsm\localprovider\baseprovider\lib\baseprovider.cpp(604)\NPSMDesktopProvider.dll!00007FF884262140: (caller: 00007FF8842626E5) ReturnHr(66) tid(141c) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.     
00000040    50.23253632 [1088] shell\explorer\taskband2\taskband2.cpp(4148)\Explorer.EXE!00007FF63FA3792A: (caller: 00007FF8C51C7DE3) ReturnHr(211) tid(b3c) 80004005 Odefinierat fel   
00000041    174.82708740    [1088] avcore\npsm\localprovider\baseprovider\lib\baseprovider.cpp(604)\NPSMDesktopProvider.dll!00007FF884262140: (caller: 00007FF8842626E5) ReturnHr(67) tid(141c) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.     
00000042    184.06332397    [1088] avcore\npsm\localprovider\baseprovider\lib\baseprovider.cpp(604)\NPSMDesktopProvider.dll!00007FF884262140: (caller: 00007FF8842626E5) ReturnHr(68) tid(141c) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.     
00000043    184.06378174    [1088] onecore\base\appmodel\resourcepolicy\gameconfigstore\client\gameconfigstoreclient.cpp(104)\resourcepolicyclient.dll!00007FF8C259976C: (caller: 00007FF8A71386C3) LogHr(38) tid(2d24) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.     
00000044    184.12196350    [1088] shell\explorer\taskband2\taskband2.cpp(4148)\Explorer.EXE!00007FF63FA3792A: (caller: 00007FF8C51C7DE3) ReturnHr(212) tid(b3c) 80004005 Odefinierat fel   
00000045    186.39077759    [4992] Warning: QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)    
00000046    186.39079285    [4992] Warning: QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (-1)   
00000047    188.62876892    [4992] Warning: QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)    
00000048    188.62879944    [4992] Warning: QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (-1)   
00000049    189.02656555    [1088] avcore\npsm\localprovider\baseprovider\lib\baseprovider.cpp(604)\NPSMDesktopProvider.dll!00007FF884262140: (caller: 00007FF8842626E5) ReturnHr(69) tid(141c) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.     
00000050    194.32499695    [1088] avcore\npsm\localprovider\baseprovider\lib\baseprovider.cpp(604)\NPSMDesktopProvider.dll!00007FF884262140: (caller: 00007FF8842626E5) ReturnHr(70) tid(141c) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.     
00000051    194.38928223    [1088] shell\explorer\taskband2\taskband2.cpp(4148)\Explorer.EXE!00007FF63FA3792A: (caller: 00007FF8C51C7DE3) ReturnHr(213) tid(b3c) 80004005 Odefinierat fel   
00000052    205.76727295    [4992] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(285)\thumbcache.dll!00007FF8A6FF8AEE: (caller: 00007FF8A6FF8D0F) ReturnHr(1) tid(2eac) 80004005 Odefinierat fel    
00000053    205.76736450    [4992] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(159)\thumbcache.dll!00007FF8A6FF4B60: (caller: 00007FF8C3C385C4) ReturnHr(2) tid(2eac) 80004005 Odefinierat fel    
00000054    205.76821899    [4992] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(285)\thumbcache.dll!00007FF8A6FF8AEE: (caller: 00007FF8A6FF8D0F) ReturnHr(3) tid(2eac) 80004005 Odefinierat fel    
00000055    205.76832581    [4992] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(159)\thumbcache.dll!00007FF8A6FF4B60: (caller: 00007FF8C3C385C4) ReturnHr(4) tid(2eac) 80004005 Odefinierat fel    
00000056    205.76867676    [4992] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(285)\thumbcache.dll!00007FF8A6FF8AEE: (caller: 00007FF8A6FF8D0F) ReturnHr(5) tid(2eac) 80004005 Odefinierat fel    
00000057    205.76882935    [4992] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(159)\thumbcache.dll!00007FF8A6FF4B60: (caller: 00007FF8C3C385C4) ReturnHr(6) tid(2eac) 80004005 Odefinierat fel    
00000058    205.76940918    [4992] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(285)\thumbcache.dll!00007FF8A6FF8AEE: (caller: 00007FF8A6FF8D0F) ReturnHr(7) tid(2eac) 80004005 Odefinierat fel    
00000059    205.76953125    [4992] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(159)\thumbcache.dll!00007FF8A6FF4B60: (caller: 00007FF8C3C385C4) ReturnHr(8) tid(2eac) 80004005 Odefinierat fel    
00000060    205.76998901    [4992] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(285)\thumbcache.dll!00007FF8A6FF8AEE: (caller: 00007FF8A6FF8D0F) ReturnHr(9) tid(2eac) 80004005 Odefinierat fel    
00000061    205.77040100    [4992] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(159)\thumbcache.dll!00007FF8A6FF4B60: (caller: 00007FF8C3C385C4) ReturnHr(10) tid(2eac) 80004005 Odefinierat fel   
00000062    205.77072144    [4992] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(285)\thumbcache.dll!00007FF8A6FF8AEE: (caller: 00007FF8A6FF8D0F) ReturnHr(11) tid(2eac) 80004005 Odefinierat fel   
00000063    205.77111816    [4992] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(159)\thumbcache.dll!00007FF8A6FF4B60: (caller: 00007FF8C3C385C4) ReturnHr(12) tid(2eac) 80004005 Odefinierat fel   
00000064    205.77461243    [4992] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(285)\thumbcache.dll!00007FF8A6FF8AEE: (caller: 00007FF8A6FF8D0F) ReturnHr(13) tid(2eac) 80004005 Odefinierat fel   
00000065    205.77525330    [4992] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(285)\thumbcache.dll!00007FF8A6FF8AEE: (caller: 00007FF8A6FF8D0F) ReturnHr(14) tid(2eac) 80004005 Odefinierat fel   
00000066    205.77577209    [4992] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(285)\thumbcache.dll!00007FF8A6FF8AEE: (caller: 00007FF8A6FF8D0F) ReturnHr(15) tid(2eac) 80004005 Odefinierat fel   
00000067    205.77644348    [4992] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(285)\thumbcache.dll!00007FF8A6FF8AEE: (caller: 00007FF8A6FF8D0F) ReturnHr(16) tid(2eac) 80004005 Odefinierat fel   
00000068    205.77690125    [4992] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(285)\thumbcache.dll!00007FF8A6FF8AEE: (caller: 00007FF8A6FF8D0F) ReturnHr(17) tid(2eac) 80004005 Odefinierat fel   
00000069    205.77783203    [4992] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(285)\thumbcache.dll!00007FF8A6FF8AEE: (caller: 00007FF8A6FF8D0F) ReturnHr(18) tid(2eac) 80004005 Odefinierat fel   
00000070    205.78169250    [4992] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(285)\thumbcache.dll!00007FF8A6FF8AEE: (caller: 00007FF8A6FF8D0F) ReturnHr(19) tid(2eac) 80004005 Odefinierat fel   
00000071    205.78273010    [4992] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(285)\thumbcache.dll!00007FF8A6FF8AEE: (caller: 00007FF8A6FF8D0F) ReturnHr(20) tid(2eac) 80004005 Odefinierat fel   
00000072    205.78538513    [4992] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(285)\thumbcache.dll!00007FF8A6FF8AEE: (caller: 00007FF8A6FF8D0F) ReturnHr(21) tid(2eac) 80004005 Odefinierat fel   
00000073    205.78787231    [4992] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(285)\thumbcache.dll!00007FF8A6FF8AEE: (caller: 00007FF8A6FF8D0F) ReturnHr(22) tid(2eac) 80004005 Odefinierat fel   
00000074    205.78997803    [4992] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(285)\thumbcache.dll!00007FF8A6FF8AEE: (caller: 00007FF8A6FF8D0F) ReturnHr(23) tid(2eac) 80004005 Odefinierat fel   
00000075    205.79199219    [4992] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(285)\thumbcache.dll!00007FF8A6FF8AEE: (caller: 00007FF8A6FF8D0F) ReturnHr(24) tid(2eac) 80004005 Odefinierat fel   
00000076    216.14601135    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(733) tid(31ec) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.   
00000077    216.14625549    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(732) tid(129c) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.   
00000078    216.14642334    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(734) tid(31ec) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.   
00000079    216.14653015    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(735) tid(f74) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.    
00000080    216.14663696    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(736) tid(c5c) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.    
00000081    216.14671326    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(737) tid(31ec) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.   
00000082    216.14704895    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(738) tid(f74) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.    
00000083    216.14718628    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(740) tid(c5c) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.    
00000084    216.14724731    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(739) tid(129c) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.   
00000085    216.14732361    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(741) tid(31ec) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.   
00000086    216.14749146    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(742) tid(f74) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.    
00000087    216.14753723    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(743) tid(c5c) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.    
00000088    216.14772034    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(745) tid(31ec) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.   
00000089    216.14781189    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(746) tid(f74) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.    
00000090    216.14788818    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(744) tid(129c) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.   
00000091    216.14813232    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(747) tid(c5c) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.    
00000092    216.14819336    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(748) tid(f74) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.    
00000093    216.14823914    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(749) tid(129c) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.   
00000094    216.14859009    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(750) tid(c5c) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.    
00000095    216.14880371    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(751) tid(129c) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.   
00000096    216.15356445    [1088] shell\explorer\taskband2\taskband2.cpp(4148)\Explorer.EXE!00007FF63FA3792A: (caller: 00007FF8C51C7DE3) ReturnHr(214) tid(b3c) 80004005 Odefinierat fel   
00000097    216.48939514    [1088] shell\explorer\taskband2\taskband2.cpp(4148)\Explorer.EXE!00007FF63FA3792A: (caller: 00007FF8C51C7DE3) ReturnHr(215) tid(b3c) 80004005 Odefinierat fel   
00000098    216.59118652    [4992] Warning: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 0h: PCS illuminant is not D50  
00000099    216.59315491    [4992] Warning: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 0h: PCS illuminant is not D50  
00000100    216.75190735    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(752) tid(129c) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.   
00000101    216.75221252    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(753) tid(c5c) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.    
00000102    216.75244141    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(754) tid(f74) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.    
00000103    216.75302124    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(755) tid(129c) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.   
00000104    216.75314331    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(756) tid(31ec) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.   
00000105    216.75323486    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(757) tid(c5c) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.    
00000106    216.75340271    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(758) tid(f74) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.    
00000107    216.75355530    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(759) tid(129c) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.   
00000108    216.75379944    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(760) tid(31ec) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.   
00000109    216.75404358    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(761) tid(c5c) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.    
00000110    216.75444031    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(762) tid(f74) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.    
00000111    216.75502014    [1088] shell\lib\bindctx.cpp(128)\explorerframe.dll!00007FF8A901F200: (caller: 00007FF8A90424EA) ReturnHr(763) tid(31ec) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.   
00000112    218.51824951    [4992] Warning: QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)    
00000113    218.51832581    [4992] Warning: QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (-1)   
00000114    220.71968079    [4992] Warning: QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)    
00000115    220.71968079    [4992] Warning: QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (-1)   
00000116    220.89567566    [4992] Warning: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 0h: PCS illuminant is not D50  
00000117    220.89759827    [4992] Warning: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 0h: PCS illuminant is not D50  
00000118    222.70550537    [4992] Warning: QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)    
00000119    222.70558167    [4992] Warning: QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (-1)   
00000120    224.87599182    [4992] Warning: QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)    
00000121    224.87600708    [4992] Warning: QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (-1)   
00000122    284.46606445    [4992] Warning: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 0h: PCS illuminant is not D50  
00000123    284.46801758    [4992] Warning: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 0h: PCS illuminant is not D50  
00000124    286.99746704    [4992] Warning: QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)    
00000125    286.99749756    [4992] Warning: QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (-1)   
00000126    289.64855957    [4992] Warning: QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (0)    
00000127    289.64855957    [4992] Warning: QFont::setPixelSize: Pixel size <= 0 (-1)   
00000128    335.72167969    [4992] Warning: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 0h: PCS illuminant is not D50  
00000129    335.72372437    [4992] Warning: libpng warning: iCCP: profile 'icc': 0h: PCS illuminant is not D50  
00000130    341.02783203    [1088] onecore\base\appmodel\resourcepolicy\gameconfigstore\client\gameconfigstoreclient.cpp(104)\resourcepolicyclient.dll!00007FF8C259976C: (caller: 00007FF8A71386C3) LogHr(39) tid(eec) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.  
00000131    341.02789307    [1088] avcore\npsm\localprovider\baseprovider\lib\baseprovider.cpp(604)\NPSMDesktopProvider.dll!00007FF884262140: (caller: 00007FF8842626E5) ReturnHr(71) tid(141c) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.     
00000132    350.42520142    [1088] avcore\npsm\localprovider\baseprovider\lib\baseprovider.cpp(604)\NPSMDesktopProvider.dll!00007FF884262140: (caller: 00007FF8842626E5) ReturnHr(72) tid(141c) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.     
00000133    352.73049927    [3692] shell\comdlg32\fileopensave.cpp(6774)\COMDLG32.dll!7515EBEB: (caller: 75135A0B) ReturnHr(1) tid(3148) 80004005 Odefinierat fel   
00000134    352.73049927    [3692]     CallContext:[\PickerModalLoop\InitDialog]    
00000135    354.23052979    [12668] SetProcessDpiAwareness(2) failed: COM error 0x80070005  (Unknown error 0x0ffffffff80070005), using 2    
00000136    469.26406860    [3692] onecoreuap\shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(285)\thumbcache.dll!7350FEFF: (caller: 734FEF51) ReturnHr(1) tid(3148) 80004005 Odefinierat fel    
00000137    469.29336548    [9196] shell\explorer\traysearchhelper.h(80)\explorer.exe!00007FF63FA79576: (caller: 00007FF63FA7B013) ReturnHr(4) tid(23f8) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.    
00000138    469.31640625    [9196] shell\lib\immersiveapphelpers\immersiveappiconhelpers.cpp(310)\explorer.exe!00007FF63FA6A610: (caller: 00007FF63FA6B93D) ReturnHr(6) tid(2b2c) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.  
00000139    469.31640625    [9196]     CallContext:[\LoadIconW]     
00000140    469.33987427    [9196] shell\explorer\searchbutton.cpp(236)\explorer.exe!00007FF63FA7B032: (caller: 00007FF63FA55B61) ReturnHr(7) tid(23f8) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.     
00000141    469.36911011    [9196] shell\explorer\tray.cpp(3938)\explorer.exe!00007FF63FA4018B: (caller: 00007FF63FA4018B) LogHr(1) tid(2b2c) 80070057 Felaktig parameter.  
00000142    469.39663696    [9196] shell\explorer\traysearchhelper.h(80)\explorer.exe!00007FF63FA79576: (caller: 00007FF63FA7B013) ReturnHr(8) tid(23f8) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.    
00000143    469.41940308    [9196] shell\explorer\searchbutton.cpp(236)\explorer.exe!00007FF63FA7B032: (caller: 00007FF63FA55B61) ReturnHr(9) tid(23f8) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.     
00000144    469.44177246    [9196] shell\explorer\traysearchhelper.h(80)\explorer.exe!00007FF63FA79576: (caller: 00007FF63FA7B013) ReturnHr(10) tid(23f8) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.   
00000145    469.46475220    [9196] shell\explorer\searchbutton.cpp(236)\explorer.exe!00007FF63FA7B032: (caller: 00007FF63FA55B61) ReturnHr(11) tid(23f8) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.    
00000146    469.48596191    [9196] shell\explorer\traysearchhelper.h(80)\explorer.exe!00007FF63FA79576: (caller: 00007FF63FA7B013) ReturnHr(12) tid(23f8) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.   
00000147    469.51040649    [9196] shell\explorer\searchbutton.cpp(236)\explorer.exe!00007FF63FA7B032: (caller: 00007FF63FA55B61) ReturnHr(13) tid(23f8) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.    
00000148    469.73080444    [9196] shell\explorer\traysearchhelper.h(80)\explorer.exe!00007FF63FA79576: (caller: 00007FF63FA7B013) ReturnHr(14) tid(23f8) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.   
00000149    469.73355103    [9196] shell\explorer\searchbutton.cpp(236)\explorer.exe!00007FF63FA7B032: (caller: 00007FF63FA55B61) ReturnHr(15) tid(23f8) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.    
00000150    469.76727295    [9196] shell\explorer\traysearchhelper.h(80)\explorer.exe!00007FF63FA79576: (caller: 00007FF63FA7B013) ReturnHr(16) tid(23f8) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.   
00000151    469.77499390    [9196] shell\explorer\searchbutton.cpp(236)\explorer.exe!00007FF63FA7B032: (caller: 00007FF63FA55B61) ReturnHr(17) tid(23f8) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.    
00000152    470.22988892    [4944] onecoreuap\base\appmodel\execmodel\modern\lifetimemanager\plmdata.cpp(970)\modernexecserver.dll!00007FF8ACEE86C6: (caller: 00007FF8ACF314A0) ReturnHr(86) tid(2850) 8002802B Det gick inte att hitta elementet.  
00000153    470.24496460    [4944] onecoreuap\base\appmodel\execmodel\modern\lifetimemanager\plmdata.cpp(970)\modernexecserver.dll!00007FF8ACEE86C6: (caller: 00007FF8ACF314A0) ReturnHr(87) tid(2850) 8002802B Det gick inte att hitta elementet.  
00000154    470.25292969    [4944] onecoreuap\base\appmodel\execmodel\modern\lifetimemanager\plmdata.cpp(970)\modernexecserver.dll!00007FF8ACEE86C6: (caller: 00007FF8ACF314A0) ReturnHr(89) tid(2850) 8002802B Det gick inte att hitta elementet.  
00000155    470.26098633    [4944] onecoreuap\base\appmodel\execmodel\modern\lifetimemanager\suspendresume.cpp(3837)\modernexecserver.dll!00007FF8ACEDFCC3: (caller: 00007FF8ACF0CAD2) ReturnHr(88) tid(2b6c) 8000000D En ogiltig tillståndsförändring begärdes.    
00000156    470.27902222    [4944] onecoreuap\base\appmodel\execmodel\modern\lifetimemanager\suspendresume.cpp(3837)\modernexecserver.dll!00007FF8ACEDFCC3: (caller: 00007FF8ACF0CAD2) ReturnHr(90) tid(2b6c) 8000000D En ogiltig tillståndsförändring begärdes.    
00000157    470.34518433    [9196] onecoreuap\base\diagnosis\platform\notifications\platform\settings\globalsettingsimpl.cpp(2562)\wpncore.dll!00007FF8B94F9C9B: (caller: 00007FF8B94747ED) ReturnHr(1) tid(17a0) 80070002 Det går inte att hitta filen.    
00000158    470.38458252    [9196] onecoreuap\base\diagnosis\platform\notifications\platform\settings\globalsettingsimpl.cpp(2138)\wpncore.dll!00007FF8B947480A: (caller: 00007FF8B9495A23) LogHr(1) tid(17a0) 80070002 Det går inte att hitta filen.   
00000159    470.40954590    [9196] onecoreuap\base\diagnosis\platform\notifications\platform\sqlitewrapper\statement.cpp(83)\wpncore.dll!00007FF8B9467006: (caller: 00007FF8B94694F7) Exception(1) tid(17a0) 87AF0813 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE  
00000160    470.41207886    [9196] onecoreuap\base\diagnosis\platform\notifications\platform\database\sqlitedatabase.cpp(684)\wpncore.dll!00007FF8B94A523D: (caller: 00007FF8B947319C) ReturnHr(2) tid(17a0) 87AF0813 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE  
00000161    470.41207886    [9196]     Msg:[onecoreuap\base\diagnosis\platform\notifications\platform\sqlitewrapper\statement.cpp(83)\wpncore.dll!00007FF8B9467006: (caller: 00007FF8B94694F7) Exception(1) tid(17a0) 87AF0813 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE     
00000162    470.41207886    [9196] ]    
00000163    470.73526001    [9196] onecoreuap\base\diagnosis\platform\notifications\platform\database\databasehelpers.cpp(143)\wpncore.dll!00007FF8B9461579: (caller: 00007FF8B949C335) ReturnHr(3) tid(81c) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.    
00000164    470.74182129    [9196] onecoreuap\base\diagnosis\platform\notifications\platform\database\databasehelpers.cpp(143)\wpncore.dll!00007FF8B9461579: (caller: 00007FF8B949C335) ReturnHr(4) tid(81c) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.    
00000165    470.80535889    [9196] onecoreuap\base\diagnosis\platform\notifications\platform\database\databasehelpers.cpp(143)\wpncore.dll!00007FF8B9461579: (caller: 00007FF8B94622CF) ReturnHr(5) tid(d8c) 80070490 Det gick inte att hitta elementet.
```

Comment: To me, the best option is to switch to PostGIS or SpatiaLite. I had a lot of issues using shape files, perhaps caused by missing primary keys. I don't know ...

Comment: @Benjamin Donner - Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: Thank you for asking @MartinHügi  , no unfortunately I have not resolved it. I tried to learn how to convert from ESRI shape to PostGIS or SpatiaLite but there seemed to be such a huge amount of work included that I have now slowly started to rebuild the whole masive project.  All is well as long as I am working with the project in QGIS (well, a crash or two every now and then but not often), but immediately when I try creating any bigger maps in the composer the system crashes.  I have done validity checks, they show nothing.

Comment: You could try looking at an answer I gave the other day about setting up a PostGIS database http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232945/how-do-i-setup-a-postgis-database-and-open-it-in-qgis-with-no-ubuntu/233024#233024

Comment: @MartinHügi if you have the time: Does these DebugView -rows tell anything about what happens when qgis crashes?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8nu0fx4prwwj2lp/crash-moment.txt?dl=0

Comment: Sorry, I am afraid they don't mean anything to me. I still think that you need to try putting all your shapefiles into a PostGIS database and then run some scripts to check them for geometry errors. Then work with them in QGIS from PostGIS. Setting up a local instance of PostGIS would probably be the simplest. What is your operating system?

Comment: @MartinHügi I have done some tries to create a PostGIS database according with your advice but I am not able to connect with localhost. I think I have to try reinstalling all (tried installing pgAdmin 4 and running installation of PostGIS / spatial database trough StackBuilder, which in the end of the installation gives a  could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061) )

Comment: It's worth persevering. Perhaps post a question showing what you have tried, and how your circumstances differ from the steps in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232945/how-do-i-setup-a-postgis-database-and-open-it-in-qgis-on-windows/233024#233024

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 1):

To check esri shapefiles for problems that might make qgis crash you could try checking the geometry validity of each shapefile.

Go to Vector > Geometry Tools > Check Geometry Validity.

Or use Processing Toolbox. Go to Processing > Toolbox > Vector geometry tools > Check validity.

This can find various errors in the geometry that I have found causes problems in the past.

With so many large shapefiles you could look at putting them into a PostGIS database and working with them in your project that way.

Answer (score 1):

After checking all ESRI Shapefile layers for geometry validity (OK), exporting all layers to PostGIS (did not help), and trying to reimport and re-style some of the layers I had most doubts about (did not help):

By disabling groups of layers and using a simple but many days time taking exclusion method, I got confirmed that a layer with a lot of data rows (190.000 rows) of lines (roads) was at least one cause of crashes. This table had nothing wrong in it, but after many tests, I found out that each time that I checked the checkmark "Control Feature Rendering Order" under the Layer properties, and then trying to render the map at cetain zoom levels or evertime I tried to print an atlas, QGIS crashed. This was the same for all versions of QGIS I tried (2.18, 2.99, 2.16).

I tried the same with other large data sets, which confirmed the result: Big data sets combined with the "Control Feature Rendering Order" checkmark makes QGIS crash.