# Reading/writing local datastore for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, file-geodatabase, software-recommendations, spatialite, spatial-database

What is a solution for reading/writing a local datastore for QGIS?

I've got data that's too large for a shapefile, I need lengthy column titles, but don't want to be logging into a remote server. 
I've been giving Spatialite a good go but seem to bump up against limitations like not being able to delete columns plus it seems there is little development going on in this space.  I use the QSpatialite plugin.

I'm thinking I should be getting in db views, but don't see any workflows there for Spatialite.

Is there another option for a FOSS local datastore?

Comment: these words from Sandro himself `anyway please carefully consider just a couple of further details: 
- in SQLite implementing a Writable View is certainly possible, 
   but critically depends on Trigger actions 
- in very few words: it's like walking on thin ice.`

Comment: I would stil suggest to use either SpatiaLite or GeoPackage. Keep Spatialite-gui available if you want to drop columns or create views.

Comment: H2GIS is another single file GIS database. It has many nice features. Hardly anybody is using it.

Comment: user30184, I spent some time looking there at H2GIS, but it is not able to connect to QGIS?

Comment: And now I can't seem to get SpatiaLite-Gui established on this machine!! Frustration.

Comment: No, QGIS can't connect with H2GIS. Orbit GIS and OpenJUMP can.

Answer (score 11):

How about a local PostGIS instance? PostgeSQL can be downloaded from https://www.postgresql.org/download/ to which a PostGIS extension can be created to make it a spatial database. Also recommended would be to download pgAdmin https://www.pgadmin.org/

See [How do I setup a PostGIS database and open it in QGIS on Windows?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232945/how-do-i-setup-a-postgis-database-and-open-it-in-qgis-on-windows/233024#233024) which may help with the set up.

Comment: One additional point, Postgres is extremely powerful, and FAST!

Comment: Yes, I have had some experience with PostGIS, but the establishment, maintenance and lack of portability of that is a discouragement. Thanks

Comment: There is a portable PostGIS http://www.archaeogeek.com/portable-gis.html  and  http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/172-Starting-PostgreSQL-in-windows-without-install.html

Comment: @BillW Did you come up with a satisfactory solution to a FOSS datastore?